# Next.js App reloads frequently in production

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, webpack, next.js

I've just deployed my first Next.js app in production through Nginx and pm2. Everything seems okay but the app frequently reloads after some interval on browser. I'm seeing the `webpack-hmr` is also running in my `production` server. (Which I think isn't necessary in production)

I am using a custom `server.js` and I run my app on production using `next build` then `NODE_ENV=production node server.js` command, and restarting my server using `pm2`.

I've added below a screenshot of my dev-tool's network tab which is showing the HMR running on `production`. If `HMR` is the possible cause of browser reload, then what should I do to disable it on production?

And also if the "frequent reload" isn't happening because of HMR then what will be the cause of it?

[image: Screenshot of my network tab of devtools showing HMR running]

Have you guys experienced the same issue on production? If so, please share your knowledge and experience. Thanks.

**Edit:** I am also using [next-pwa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa) and a warning keeps showing on my console for it -

> GenerateSW has been called multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution. I had to tell my env mode when starting pm2 as `pm2 start server --env production`. And it works perfectly on my browser.

Answer (score 13):

Fixed it by disabling `pwa` when in development

```js
const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = withPWA({
            pwa: {
                dest: 'public',
                disable: prod ? false : true
                }
             })
```